# Left Command + Z isn't working anymore

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I have a full size Apple keyboard attached to my MacBook Pro. The left <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> key combination isn't working since a while.

1. The problem only occurs when using the left Command key. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is working fine.
2. The left Command key works fine with other combinations, such as left <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
3. The problem only occurs when using the external keyboard. Left <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is working fine on the MacBook itself.

I tried restoring the keyboard settings to its defaults, to no avail. This could be a hardware problem, but I can't understand why the left Command key works fine in combination with other keys.

I'm clearly lost here. Any ideas?

Edit: Tested the keyboard on another MacBook and it's having the same issues. So, it's most likely a hardware issue. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it! Cleaned the area underneath the Z key and everything is working again. :-)